# Can't login to Stack Overflow under Firefox

Tags: support

Faced with odd Stack Overflow behavio when use Firefox 32 under Windows 7.

First click `log in`, then press `Login in using Facebook`, got message on top '*Welcome back*, setevoy', and - redirect to first page, but not logged.

Also - log in works on other sites (DBA, Code Review, Unix etc).

I made [small video](http://rtfm.co.ua/uploads/stack_login2.avi), if it can help.

Comment: Over 500Mb is a small video? Are you using HTTPS everywhere? Any add-ons/plugins?

Comment: Oh, sorry... When 100 mb/s internet - dosn't think about size. 'Small' - i mean it's few minutes :-) Could clarify about https? Sure - I use it, in Firefox, on lot of websites. And yes - I have some plugins (AdBlock Plus, for example). Will try tomorrow disable them and log in again. Thanks for idea.

Comment: I have same problem too. firefox  version : 32.0.3 .(I tried disabling all plugins, clearing cache ...  )

Comment: Seeems to work OK with W7-64bit, (so Anne tells me from downstairs with the TV server running FF with Facebook:).

Comment: With disabled plugins - same problem.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and all cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed using the [Firefox Support Knowledge Base](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-login-issues-on-websites-require-passwords).